# Why this is not grammar LL(1)

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar, ll-grammar

I have been given a task to transform this grammar to LL(1)

```
E → E+E | E-E | E*E | E/E | E^E | -E | (E)| id | num
```

So for first step I eliminated ambiguity and got this:

```
E → E+T | E-T | T 
T → T*P | T/P | P
P → P ^ F | F
F → id | num | -E | (E)
```

And after that I have eliminated left-recursion and got this:

```
E  → TE'
E' → +TE' | -TE' | ɛ
T  → PT'
T' → *PT' | /PT' | ɛ
P  → FP'
P' → ^FP' | ɛ
F  → id | num | -E | (E)
```

When I put this into JFLAP and click 'Build LL(1) parse table' I get warning that grammar above is not LL(1).

Why this grammar is not LL(1), and what do I need to change to be LL(1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your grammar is still ambiguous, so it can't be LL(1).

This production `F → -E` makes it possible to mix an expression with lower precedence operators in a level (unary operator) where they shouldn't appear.

Note that `id + - id + id` has two derivation trees.

You shouldn't use `E` there, but a symbol that represents an atomic value. You could replace

```
F → id | num | -E | (E)
```

with

```
F → -A | A
A → id | num | (E)
```

Or `F → -F | A` if you want to allow multiple unary minuses.

Comment: Or `F  → id | num | -F | (E)` if you don't want to introduce yet another non-terminal

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have introduces new terminal symbol like you did and it works now.